# WP7 Binding a value itself

Tags: windows-phone-7, binding

If I have

```
<SomeTag x:Key="Name">AVALUE</SomeTag>
```

How to bind SomeTag? I need to set AVALUE from binding,
I want to make something like we use on Styles:

```
<Setter Property="Name" Value="AVALUE"/>
```

so I could set instead of AVALUE  -> {Binding ....}

It must be something simple, but I don't know what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
<SomeTag x:Key="Name" Content="{Binding SomeProperty}" />
```

The *default* property for the content between the start and end tag, is `Content`. But it could be a different property (like `Text` for most FlowDocument elements).

The documentation should tell you so.

Comment: There is no Content in Color tag :(

Comment: Read this part again: *[The documentation should tell you so.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color_properties.aspx)*. You can only bind the properties available, which would be the ARGB values for your colour.